# Minimize startup time for asp.net

Tags: .net, asp.net, performance, iis, startup

I have multiple web services (WCF) running in IIS. When the services are warm (loaded), typical requests take about 0.5 seconds to complete. However, when the application is not warm (cold start), the first hit takes some 20 seconds before the service is up and running. The same happens when an app pool recycle occurs.

I'm looking to reduce the cold start times for this web service. Some actions i have already performed are:

- Configured the application pool so that it doesn't recycle after 20 min, idle time (so that the application stays warm). **This minimizes the occurence of cold starts, but doesn't make cold starts faster**. app pool recycles are now limited, but do stil occur.
- Modified the machine.config,

like this:

```
<runtime>
    <!-- see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629393(v=vs.90).aspx -->
    <generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false"/>
</runtime>
```

**This reduces startup times from 20 secs to about 10 secs.**

- I've tried using `NGEN` to precompile the assemblies,

like this

```
for %d in (*.dll) do ngen install %d
```

**This doesn't reduce startup times** (only adds complexity to deployment).

**I would really like to reduce the cold start times even further. What options do i have to do this?**

(on a side note: what is the best way to find out where the time is spend during startup? how do i monitor what's going on?)

Comment: What version of IIS? Can you install [AppFabric](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/app-main.aspx)?

Comment: IIS 6 on Windows 2003. How can AppFabric help with startup times?

Comment: AppFabric has an auto start feature will prevent the warm up delays. Here's a blog post for you, but this is only available in IIS 7.5., so it won't help you any. If you can't use AppFabric, consider self hosting your WCF services. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabriccat/archive/2010/10/29/how-using-appfabric-auto-start-feature-to-avoid-warm-up-delays-for-iis-hosted-wcf-receive-locations.aspx

Comment: If you decide to go the self hosting route, check out ECollective: http://www.soacollective.com/solutions/ecollective/ecollective-features/

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/590865/how-can-i-warm-up-my-asp-net-mvc-webapp-after-an-app-pool-recycle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

I've done some further testing with `procmon`. There doesn't seem to be one single cause of the start up time, it's a whole lot of little timeslices (proces start, loading ,net runtime, reading configuration, loading assemblies, etc..) that add up to the total time.

Comment: i know it is not nice to accept your own answer, but in this case i think it is the most correct way to do it.

Comment: I don't suppose you remember what proportion of that was taken up by copying the assemblies to the C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files folder? Just out of curiosity -

Comment: nope, sorry. i used .net 3.5 by the way. and i don't think there will be (much) assemblies copied anyway, since we use precompiled assemblies.

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ Any chance you could point me in the right direction, how to use procmon to detect the source of the lag?

Comment: @manishKungwani take a look at the SysInternals Suite which you can find at http://live.sysinternals.com/ procmon is a process monitor that can track all kind of windows events for running processes. You can determine times between events, to pinpoint where delays occurr.

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ I am familiar with procmon, I just wanted to know, which events do I need to look out for?

Comment: @manishKungwani I just used the filtering options so that only the events originating from my application were visible. You will have to try to make sense of the logs yourself i'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

I've had decent luck with the strategy found in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASPNETService.aspx). It keeps the application alive so that once it's running, you just won't have any cold starts (unless IIS or the machine is actually restarted intentionally or as the result of a significant error). The app keeps itself alive regardless of any activity.

The article is about scheduling something to happen every so-often, but you can skip that part if your only goal is to keep the app alive.

Comment: the problem isn't the number of recycles (see my first bullet), it's the duration that a cold start takes.

Comment: Yep, it won't answer your question, but if your application never actually cold-starts (except after a true outage), then the cold-start time won't really be an issue, since it will never happen.